# PowerShell Metadata Navigational Menu of Simple Links from excel file in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, managed-navigation

[image]Can any one tell me how to update the url for a group of terms from excel through powershell script in sharepoint 2013.

Please find the screen shot for the same

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script which can do the same

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity $siteName
$session = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $siteName
$termStore = $session.TermStores[$termStoreName]
$Group = $termStore.Groups["Group Name"]

$Group.SetLocalCustomProperty("_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl", "URL")
$termStore.CommitAll()
```

Comment: Ok That is for the group what about the Terms and Child ones.I need to do in a bunch with powershell script

Comment: You can loop through the group and do the same

Comment: I Got it working thanks  see my answer below. One last question. is it possible to set the url from CSV file becase i have more than 200 terms and setting like this takes lot of time. Any idea is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I Got it working thanks see my answer below. One last question. is it possible to set the url from CSV file becase i have more than 200 terms and setting like this takes lot of time. Any idea is highly appreciated –

```
$siteCollectionUrl = "http://sp2013:90"
$site =new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteCollectionUrl)
$session = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession($site)
$termStore = $session.TermStores[0]
$group = $termStore.Groups["Corporate Taxonomy"]
$termSet = $group.TermSets["Geography"]
$terms = $termSet.GetAllTerms()
foreach ($term in $terms)
{
    if ($term.Name -eq "Durban")
    {
        Write-Host "Drban Found!"
        $term.SetLocalCustomProperty("_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl", "Www.Google.com")

    }

$termStore.CommitAll()

}
```

Comment: You should not ask new questions in answers

Comment: Robert it is in the same question. Please see my initital question where i have asked to read the data from excel

Comment: I do see that, but your answer is not really following the standard format of the site. Maybe you should move the info from this answer to the body of your post instead, and delete this answer?